# Javascript When looping through array, webpage freezes/crashes

Tags: javascript, arrays, crash

So, as the title suggests, when I am looping through a array to do collision in my game, it crashes. Let me give you some more details, when looping through the array, I go through the array once to check collisions for a set object, and use another array to loop through the objects again to do the collision. In a very specific case, the website will crash. When the object collides into a corner and hits both walls, the webpage just stops.

Here is the code for the game:

```
function RunPhysics()
{
//Move all objects
for(i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++)
{
    var obj = gameObjects[i];
    SetObjectPos(obj, obj.xPos + obj.xForce, obj.yPos + obj.yForce);
}

//Check all objects against each other for collision.
var collidedObjects = [];
for(i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++)
{
    var current = gameObjects[i];
    for(x=0; x<gameObjects.length; x++)
    {
        for(z=0; z<collidedObjects.length; z++)
        {
            --It crashes somewhere around here.
            if(collidedObjects[z] == gameObjects[i])
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

The objects each contain position, current force, color, and collision type. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? There's so much code you haven't shown.

Comment: There is a general rule of thumb in all of programming. If you are nesting the same control structure more 3 or more levels deep, you are not thinking about the problem correctly. You need to break up your work. This level of loop nesting is just begging for a crash. Also, if you are looping arrays, use `.forEach()` as it eliminates the need to manage index counters.

Comment: I try and check the console for errors, but the console crashes and won't display the errors. And the reason why I have 3 loops is because the first one is for getting the object that is colliding, the second is which object is checked against the object for collision, and the third one is for my attempt to fix the problem by doing a check to see if I can prevent the problem.

Comment: Sounds like loops 2 and 3 could be combined.

Comment: did you check if your code ends in an infinite loop for any reason ? the browser feeezing on iterations, is usually a consequence of  infinite loops

Comment: Most likely the crash happens due to the undeclared variables. Some of the functions you're calling within the loops has a conflicting variable name and that messes up one or more of the loop counters. You should always declare variables local to functions using `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: Loop 1 and 2 are the ones that matter. Loop 3 loops through all detected collisions to try and prevent the crash. Btw, the web page only crashes if one object hits a corner made of two objects, I do not believe it is the variable not being declared.

Comment: For the infinite loops, I do not know if it is a infinite loop, the page becomes unresponsive and all debugging tools crash with the page.

Comment: Use FireFox, it won't crash at infinite loops.

Comment: Hmm, I will test this and see if I can get any information. Will be a minute though since I am currently at school and the schools have a really out of date FireFox and also about to leave.

Comment: Please read also my comment about variable declaration.

Comment: I did read it. But I don’t see how I have undeclared variables. Would you please explain this further to me?

Comment: Doing some testing, FireFox did not give me any errors when the game stopped. I did look further into Teemu's comment and am now testing the physics.

Comment: Did FF show you a message saying something like "A script on this page slows Firefox down, do you want to continue to execute the script?"? Can't see undeclared variables? `for  (i = 0; ...)` where have you declared `i`, or `x` or `z` in `RunPhysics` function? If you've declared those variables as globals, and using the same names in some other functions, the values of the variables will be more or less unpredictable in any function using them.

Comment: It was those variables and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to someone in the comments, I figured it out. It was a variable that was misbehaving. 
The following is the code that I think broke it all.

```
for(i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++)
{
    var obj = gameObjects[i];
    SetObjectPos(obj, obj.xPos + obj.xForce, obj.yPos + obj.yForce);
}

//Check all objects against each other for collision.
var collidedObjects = [];
for(i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++)
{
```

Here is the changes that made it work. (Ignore the collidedObjects array being commented out)

```
for(var i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++)
{
    var obj = gameObjects[i];
    SetObjectPos(obj, obj.xPos + obj.xForce, obj.yPos + obj.yForce);
}

//Check all objects against each other for collision.
//var collidedObjects = [];
for(var i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++)
{
```

Apparently because of having the same variable being used for two loops, it caused something to break. So I just defined the variables and it worked! Hope this helps someone else who finds this :)